# How to remove parenthesis from output python

Tags: python, parentheses

So I have a function that keeps spitting out:

```
(10.3,11.4)
```

when it should be spitting out:

```
10.3 11.4
```

I played around and wrote a simple python code and I seem to understand the concept

```
a=3
b=3
print a,b #returns 3 3
```

but it is not working for the function below, so I am wondering why it keeps returning the ()

```
import math

x=10.01
y=9.01

def d():
    b = 2.00 *  x / math.sqrt(7)
    q=round(y-b,2)
    r=round(y+b,2)
    return q,r

print d() #returns (1.4399999999999999, 16.579999999999998)
```

Comment: That's a tuple.  Why don't you want it to look like a tuple?

Comment: It's a fair question: if `print d()` prints a tuple, why doesn't `print a,b`?

Comment: @Robᵩ because `d()` returns a 2-tuple and `print a,b` gives two arguments to the `print` statement.

Comment: @roippi - Correct. But I was rhetorically restating the OP's question for clarity.

Comment: @Robᵩ yeah sorry, realized that immediately after I hit enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` is (correctly) printing the tuple that is returned from d. To print the values individually, try this:

```
print '{} {}'.format(*d())
```

Or this:

```
dret = d()
print dret[0],dret[1]
```

`print a,b` doesn't interpret `a,b` as a tuple, but rather as a sequence of parameters to the `print` statement. Note that the `print` statement changes syntax in Python3 for added confusion.

To make the `a,b` case parallel to the `q,r` case, it would look more like this:

```
c = a,b
print c
```

In that case the `print` statement *would* receive a tuple, and not two individual values.

Comment: In the second example the code should be: `print dret[0], dret[1]`.

Comment: `print('{} {}'.format(*d()))` is even better as it works, and the same way, in both python 2 & python 3

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in the statement "return q, r"

You cannot return multiple values from a function.  What python is doing is creating a tuple with q and r, and returning that, as return q, r is interpreted as return (q, r)  Then print takes that and outputs a tuple.  So it is really equivelent to print (q, r)

However, print q, r is executed differently, as a multi-argument print and will print all arguments with spaces in between.

Hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: It did, thank you; how would I change the return q,r to do what I am intending it do?

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation;

- The [return](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) statement leaves the current function call with the expression list.
- An [expression list](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list) containing at least one comma yields a tuple.

So returning multiple values from a function like you do here returns them in a tuple by definition.

Try explicitly unpacking the tuple returned by `d()`:

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: x=10.01

In [3]: y=9.01

In [4]: def d():
   ...:         b = 2.00 *  x / math.sqrt(7)
   ...:         q=round(y-b,2)
   ...:         r=round(y+b,2)
   ...:         return q,r
   ...: 

In [5]: a, b = d()

In [6]: print a, b
1.44 16.58
```

Answer (score 0):

math.sqrt return a complex number with a real and an imaginary part.
Change it into math.sqrt(7).real and the complex number is a real number only.  This make the print do as you expect